# mongodb multiple bindIP

Tags: mongodb

Доброго времени суток.
Нужно реализовать доступ к БД из вне.

Пробовал так:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: [127.0.0.1,111.111.111.111]
```

пропускает абсолютно все запросы из любого IP-адреса.

Если делать через запятую:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,111.111.111.111
```

то даже не запускается.

```
● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Вто 2017-08-22 21:38:43 EEST; 934ms ago
Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
Process: 3604 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=48)
Main PID: 3604 (code=exited, status=48)
```

Comment: Что в /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log ? Ибо документация https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/ категорична: ***To bind to multiple IP addresses, enter a list of comma separated values.***

Comment: @Akina сюда не помещается. [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/f6r1ZXfG)

Comment: `2017-08-22T22:05:09.545+0300 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed Cannot assign requested address for socket: 111.111.111.111:27017` - у Вас реально есть такой IP-адрес на каком-то интерфейсе?

Comment: @Akina ну это чисто для примера, с моим тоже самое происходит

Comment: Ну если вместо указанного 111.111.111.111 там существующий адрес одного из интерфейсов, то выясняйте, почему не может сформироваться слушающий сокет. Посмотрите, не занят ли порт. Попробуйте его изменить в настройках. И т.п.